# Сохранение стандартной иконки drag&drop при перетаскивании файлов из Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop

Мой код:

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True" Background="Transparent"/>
```

Что я вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я желаю видеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом это сделать?

Comment: Icon extractedIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"FILE_PATH/ПУТЬ_К_ФАЙЛУ"); Это для получения иконки по ассоциации в самой винде. А вот что с этим делать дальше - я не знаю, так как с wpf не работал. Возможно при DragAndDrop курсор можно просто заменить значком.

Comment: :) Я говорю о стандартном механизме. Как нарисовать иконку при drag&drop я знаю. А стандартный алгоритм есть (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466208/how-to-implement-the-common-drag-and-drop-icon-in-winforms).

Comment: тогда вопрос не совсем корректен. Надо уточнять что именно не получается сделать

Comment: Не получается сделать "Сохранение стандартной иконки drag&drop при перетаскивании файлов из Windows Explorer".

Comment: Всё корректно..

Comment: т.е. вы хотите, чтобы при перетаскивании файла в окно приложения она(иконка) приобретала первоначальный вид?

Comment: Чтобы она не исчезала.

Comment: Возможно, то что тебе нужно: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamroot/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms/

Comment: Это не то, к сожалению. Пример позволяет упростить рисование иконки. Мне не нужно самостоятельно это сделать. Существует какой-то стандартный механизм - не могли же все разработчики придти к единому решению вида иконки (ссылку на похожий вопрос давал выше).

Comment: @D.Stark это то... Другого не дано. Это и есть стандартный механизм - взаимодействие с помощью COM-объектов. Просто надо понимать разницу между иконкой и курсором. Их главное отличие в том, что у курсора должна быть определена активная точка - пиксел, отмечает его точное положение на экране в любой момент времени. То, что вы видите при движении мышки - это курсор. То есть при перетаскивании вам нужно назначать изображение курсора, а так как вы хотите видеть изображение ярлыка, то вам надо выполнить преобразование иконки в курсор.

Comment: Drag&Drop так устроен, что видом курсора управляет источник перетаскивания, а не целевой элемент. Чтобы изменить вид при перетаскивании из внешнего источника, самый практичный способ -  это сделать на гриде Image с нужной иконкой и устанавливать ему Margin по событию DragOver.

Answer (score 5):

Стандартный механизм - это делегирование согласования иконки и её отрисовки стандартному COM-объекту Shell - [DragDropHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776903(v=vs.85).aspx#helper).

> The drag-and-drop helper object (CLSID_DragDropHelper) is exported by the Shell to allow targets to specify the drag image while it is over the target window.

Именно он используется при отрисовке перетаскиваемого изображения в [Chrome / Chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/f18e79d901f56154f80eea1e2218544285e62623/ui/base/dragdrop/drop_target_win.cc).

Стандартный механизм подразумевает использование работу с DragDropHelper и со стороны источника, и со стороны цели:

- создать DragDropHelper / IDragSourceHelper со стороны источника, через него задать иконку. В вашем случае - это делает Explorer.
- создать DragDropHelper / IDropTargetHelper со стороны цели, и использовать его для отрисовки, переданной источником. В примере из вопроса - это делает Хром, и это же нужно сделать вам.

Минимальная реализация IDropTargetHelper со стороны WPF:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using IDataObject_Com = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Win32Point
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("4657278A-411B-11d2-839A-00C04FD918D0")]
    public class DragDropHelper { }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("4657278B-411B-11D2-839A-00C04FD918D0")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IDropTargetHelper
    {
        void DragEnter(
            [In] IntPtr hwndTarget,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IDataObject_Com dataObject,
            [In] ref Win32Point pt,
            [In] int effect);
        void DragLeave();

        void DragOver(
            [In] ref Win32Point pt,
            [In] int effect);

        void Drop(
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IDataObject_Com dataObject,
            [In] ref Win32Point pt,
            [In] int effect);

        void Show(
            [In] bool show);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private IDropTargetHelper ddHelper = (IDropTargetHelper)new DragDropHelper();

        private void Window_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            e.Handled = true;
            Point p = this.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
            Win32Point wp;
            wp.x = (int)p.X;
            wp.y = (int)p.Y;

            ddHelper.DragEnter(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, e.Data as IDataObject_Com, ref wp, (int)e.Effects);
        }

        private void Window_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            e.Handled = true;
            Point p = this.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
            Win32Point wp;
            wp.x = (int)p.X;
            wp.y = (int)p.Y;

            ddHelper.DragOver(ref wp, (int)e.Effects);
        }

        private void Window_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            ddHelper.DragLeave();
        }

        private void Window_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            e.Handled = true;
            Point p = this.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
            Win32Point wp;
            wp.x = (int)p.X;
            wp.y = (int)p.Y;

            ddHelper.Drop(e.Data as IDataObject_Com, ref wp, (int)e.Effects);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        ...
        AllowDrop="True" 
        DragEnter="Window_DragEnter" 
        DragOver="Window_DragOver"
        DragLeave="Window_DragLeave"
        Drop="Window_Drop">
    ...
</Window>
```

Я использовал в качестве основы статью [Shell Style Drag and Drop in .NET (WPF and WinForms)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamroot/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms/). В ней, к сожалению, нет кода для WFP. Возможно, есть какие-то тонкости, специфические для WFP (например, маппинг Effect -> Effects), так что дайте знать, если нужна доработка :)

Comment: 1. Позицию мыши нужно передавать в экранных координатах, а не в относительных, т.е. `this.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));` 2. Чтобы `e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;` на самом деле применялось, нужно после этого еще установить `e.Handled = true;`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, ну и не забыть про возможное масштабирование в Windows надо, но это мелочи :)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо за фидбек, обновил код. Копипаста, правда, зашкаливает, но так нагляднее :)

Answer (score 4):

Ну ответ @PashaPash вполне исчерпывающий. Но, как я понял, вас не вставка иконки интересует, а получение исходной.

Немного изучив вопрос. Вот, что получил. Само изображение **можно** получить штатными способами. Достаточно воспользоваться e.Data.GetData("DragImageBits"), где e - DragEventArgs.

В данном случае вы получите само изображение в весьма примитивном формате. В начале идёт заголовок размером 6 int, где первые два - ширина и высота, вторые - точка захвата курсором X и Y, а последние - судя по всему либо MagicNumber, либо какая-то служебная инфа. После идёт само изображение в формате BGRA.

Код, для получения изображения:

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = null;
int Xpos = 0;
int Ypos = 0;
var stream = e.Data.GetData("DragImageBits") as MemoryStream;
if(stream == null)
    return;
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII, true))
{
   // Чтение заголовка
   reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
   int width = reader.ReadInt32();
   int height = reader.ReadInt32();
   Xpos = reader.ReadInt32();
   Ypos = reader.ReadInt32();

   // Получение исходного изображения
   reader.BaseStream.Position = 24;
   byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(width * height * 4);
   PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormats.Pbgra32;
   int stride = 4 * ((width * pixelFormat.BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32);
   bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, pixelFormat, null, data, stride);

   // Трансформация, поскольку исходное изображение перевёрнуто и отражено
   TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
   transformGroup.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(180));
   transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(-1, 1));
   bitmapSource = new TransformedBitmap(bitmapSource, transformGroup);
}
```

В результате у вас BitmapSource - исходное изображение с иконкой и названием, Xpos и Ypos - координаты точки, где курсор держит изображение.

Как это всё использовать видимо сами разберётесь.

Comment: Судя по всему, последние два числа - это хэндл картинки (чтобы не читать байты вручную) и цвет, который означает прозрачность. - структура SHDRAGIMAGE, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759778.aspx

Comment: @PashaPash насчет хендла возможно, но вот про цвет не совпадает. В данных там чистый белый без прозрачности (0xFFFFFFFF). Хотя я возможно что-то путаю.

Comment: там полудокументированный апи. вроде должен быть цвет в формате 0x00bbggrr. 0xFFFFFFFF, скорее всего, означает что цвет не задан.